# Realm in an Android Background Service

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm in my android application.I am receiving a notification from google drive via CompletionEvent so I need to modify my realm database in a service.

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

I have set my default configuration in my Application class the next way:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

And in the onCreate from my service I am getting my Realm instance like this:

```
mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

And then I use this realm instance in the service:

```
mRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        DocumentFileRealm documentFileRealm = realm.where(DocumentFileRealm.class)
                .equalTo("id", documentFileId)
                .findFirst();
        documentFileRealm.setDriveId(driveId);
    });
```

But when executing this last one the app launches the IllegalStateException. I don't know why. I am not sure if it has something to do with the way I have declared the service in my android manifest so I leave it here:

```
<service android:name=".package.UploadCompletionService" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.events.HANDLE_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Is it possible calling Realm from a background service? What is wrong with the way I am using this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try moving this `mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` to the onHandleIntent instead

Comment: It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an IntentService, you're supposed to treat the `onHandleIntent` method like the `doInBackground` method of an AsyncTask.

So it runs on the background thread and you should make sure you close the Realm in a finally block.

```
public class PollingService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            // go do some network calls/etc and get some data 
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                     realm.createAllFromJson(Customer.class, customerApi.getCustomers()); // Save a bunch of new Customer objects
                }
            });
        } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

`onCreate` runs on the UI thread, so your initialization of the Realm happens on a different thread, which is a no-go.

Comment: It was not an IntentService but a Service, anyways it works the same way and the onCreate method is running on the UI thread, thank you so much.

Comment: It throws Exception ---Async query cannot be created on current thread. Realm cannot be automatically updated on an IntentService thread

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO I am almost 120% sure that my code does NOT contain anything from the async API, so the error is somewhere in how your code differs from mine.

Comment: So I figured Out there was a different instance which was trying to access that realm!